# Exercise on topology

Tags: general-topology

"Let $(E,\tau)$ where $E=\mathbb{N}^*=\{1,2,\ldots\}$ and $\tau=\{\emptyset,E,\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}\}$, where $A_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$

Let $A=\{2n, n\in \mathbb{N}^*\}$ find $A', \overline{A}, \overset{\circ}{A}$

we have by definition : $x\in A'\Longleftrightarrow \forall V \in \mathcal{V}_x, (V\setminus\{x\}) \cap A\neq\emptyset $

for example for $x=2$ , an open containing x in $A_2=\{1,2\}$

$(A_2\setminus\{2\})\cap A= \{1\}\cap \{2,4,6,\ldots\}=\emptyset$ so $2\notin A'$ and also  $x=1\notin A'$

If $x=3$ an open containing $3$ in $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}\setminus\{3\}\cap \{2,4,6,...\}=\{2\}$ then $3\in A'$

How to obtain A' ? please

Comment: What is $A_n$? Is $A_n = \{1,…,n\}$? If so: If $τ$ ought to be a topology on $E$, it also needs to contain $E = ℕ^*$ itself, which is not of the form $A_n$ for any $n ∈ ℕ^*$. Also, I’m unsure about how to read “$\{A_n\}_{n ∈ ℕ^*}$”. I think you should write “$τ = \{∅, E\} ∪ \{A_n; n ∈ ℕ^*\}$ with $A_n = \{1, …, n\}$”.

Comment: but $\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*} A_n =\mathbb{N}^*$

Comment: @k.stm the infinet union of $A_n$ in $\mathbb{N}^*$

Comment: Yes, $A_n$ for $n ∈ ℕ^*$ is a base for the topology, but by $τ$ you probably want to the denote the topology itself, that is the set of all open sets. Since $E$ is open in $E$, it has to be in $τ$.

Comment: Why you do -1 , i begin the proof , what is this ??????

Comment: @k.stm you are right i edited the question

Comment: I didn’t downvote. Another thing: Your definition of derived sets $A'$ should have a “$≠$” instead of “$=$” at “$V\setminus \{x\} ∩ A = 0$”.

Comment: ok i don't read a seconde time

Comment: Are you not just looking for all $n$ such that $A_{n-1} \cap A \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist i don't understand your question

Comment: I was trying to suggest that the above is a simpler condition for characterising $A^\prime$, but perhaps not. Also, I don't quite see how $1 \in A^\prime$. $A_1 \in \mathcal V_1$, is it not?

Comment: you are right $1\notin A'$

Answer (score 0):

$A^\prime = \{ n :A_{n-1} \cap A \neq \emptyset \}$. That is, $A^\prime$ contains all the natural numbers greater than some even number. Hence, $A^\prime = \{3,4,5,\ldots \}$.

Comment: ok, $\overline{A}=\{2,3,4,....\}$ right ?

Comment: and $ \overset{\circ}{A}=\emptyset$

Comment: $\bar{A} = A \cup A^\prime$, so yes to your first question. Your second comment is also correct, as is easy to show.